# Does MISRA C++ Rule 14-5-1: (Do not declare a generic function in an associated namespace) apply for std::operator<<?

Tags: c++, function, generics, argument-dependent-lookup, misra

MISRA C++ 2008, Rule 14-5-1 states that "A non-member *generic function* shall only be declared in a namespace that is not an *associated namespace*".

Considering the case of (e.g) overloading the `operator<<()`, I wonder if this is not the very case to avoid with the MISRA rule. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &s, int x){    
   s << "my operator<<" << std::endl;
   return s;
}

int main() {
   std::cout << 5L << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

This results in **not** calling my output operator, but rather the STL output operator. So: is this an example of MISRA rule 14-5-1 violation where ADL picks the unintended function?

Comment: Your function declaration is not generic. Unless I misunderstand what MISRA C++ means by "generic".

Comment: It's suspicious that you're calling it with a `long` (which the standard library has an exact match for, while you have a `long` to `int` conversion) and then being surprised that it chooses the exact match.

Comment: Your operator expects an int, but you feed it a long. No wonder the standard operator is preferred. If you call `std::cout << 5`, this is an ambiguous call since two candidates are found.

Comment: Related to [misra-c-rule-14-5-1-name-of-generic-function-template-declared-in-namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039834/misra-c-rule-14-5-1-name-of-generic-function-template-declared-in-namespace-a)

Comment: Maybe I'm mislead, but I tried to do more or less did what MISRA provided:

Comment: With my non-generic `operator<<` I tried to provide an example as in MISRA `B operator+(long &rhs)`, and of course I shouldn't be surprised that this one is not taken. But if I understand MISRA right, this is the case to be avoided. For me it looks like the generic STL `operator<<()`violates this MISRA rule 14-5-1.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, that rule is to avoid that template (free) functions are used with ADL.

`operator<<()` doesn't apply, except maybe the following (because of `T`)

```
template<class charT, class traits, class T>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>&
operator<< (basic_ostream<charT,traits>&& os, const T& val);
```

but anyway, `operator` are mostly useless without ADL, or else we would have to import them before there usage (as we should do for UDL as `operator ""s`)

Better example would be `std::begin` which broke the rule:

```
std::vector<int> v;

begin(v); // -> std::begin(v)
```

I don't understand which errors that rule try to prevent.

Comment: If I understand you right, that means that the stream operator `operator<<` does *not* apply for a violation of the MISRA rule 14-5-1 (except for the quite exotic case).

Comment: It is what I mean, exactly.